# найди ошибку в js коде

Tags: javascript

```
var amountElements = 1;

        var screenWidth = screen.width;
        screenWidth(function () {
            if (screenWidth < 480){
                amountElements = 1;
            }
            else if (screenWidth < 800 && screenWidth>=480){
                amountElements = 2;
            }
            else if (screenWidth >= 800 && screenWidth < 1024){
                amountElements = 3;
            }
            else if (screenWidth >= 1024){
                amountElements = 4;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `screenWidth(function () {` с полки пирожок можно взять?

Comment: Я чето не понимаю, он создает переменную, а потом ее же использует в качестве функции, че за wtf?

Comment: @DimenSi Он вообще не понимает, что делает, даже вопрос нормально задать не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в ненужном вызове целочисленной переменной, как функции:

```
   var amountElements = 1;

    var screenWidth = screen.width;
    //screenWidth(function () {
        if (screenWidth < 480){
            amountElements = 1;
        }
        else if (screenWidth < 800 && screenWidth>=480){
            amountElements = 2;
        }
        else if (screenWidth >= 800 && screenWidth < 1024){
            amountElements = 3;
        }
        else if (screenWidth >= 1024){
            amountElements = 4;
        }
    //});
```

Вероятно, вам будет интересно почитать про [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) в CSS